# git retains remote information from a deleted repository

Tags: git, remote, repository

I cannot clone any repository anymore.

```
$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/myrep.git
Cloning into 'myrep'...
conq: repository does not exist.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The thing is my ssh `id_rsa` key is still the same. I recreated it anyway, updated it in my `BitBucket` account's ssh keys, and the same error shows up when I try to clone my repository. I tried the very same procedure on another machine (redhat) and git clone worked. So there is something happening with `git`.

Then I went in another git versioned project:

```
$ cd share-repo

$ ls -a
./          ../         .git/       .gitignore* f1*         f2*
```

I print the `git config` file:

```
$ cat .git/config
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/share-repo.git
[branch "master"]
[user]
    name = myaccount
```

I try a `pull`:

```
$ git pull -v
conq: repository does not exist.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Okay let's try a a push?

```
$ git push -v origin master
Pushing to git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/p2.git
conq: repository does not exist.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Huh? `Git` tries to push to repository p2? It should try pushing to `share-repo`... How in the hell is it trying to push to a repository which name is p2? Indeed, I had a repo named `p2` this morning, but I deleted it from my `BitBucket` account while doing some tests, then I removed the related folder `p2` from my computer. How did `git` retain information about `p2`? And above all, where is it stored, how can I reset it?

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/p2.git (fetch)  # ?!
origin  git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/p2.git (push)   # ?!
origin  git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/share-repo.git (push)
```

Strange, as we saw previously the `git config` file only holds information regarding the repo `share-repo`. Also I tried locating the string p2 in the whole folder:

```
$ grep -Rin p2 ../share-repo/
# Nothing
```

I manually recreated a repository named `p2` in `Bitbucket`.  I tried to clone it:

```
$ cd ..

$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/p2.git
Cloning into 'p2'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
Checking connectivity... done.

$ cd p2

$ cat .git/config 
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/p2.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master

$ git remote -v
origin  git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/p2.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/p2.git (push)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/p2.git (push)
```

Okay, the `git clone` worked, but now it referenced two extra lines for the remotes, one of which is duplicated. Remember those extra lines when working with the repo `share-repo`? It's about those very first two lines which are still related to the old p2 repo I had deleted.

Let's try to push some changes:

```
$ git touch .gitignore

$ git add .gitignore

$ git commit -m "first commit"

$ git push -v origin master
Pushing to git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/p2.git
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 216 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/p2.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master'
Pushing to git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/p2.git
To git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/p2.git
 = [up to date]      master -> master
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master'
Everything up-to-date
```

So git pushed to repo p2, and tried to do so a second time since the two repos have the same name and same location on my `bitbucket` account, so it obviously found that everything was up to date.

Now I could clone any repository I want, provided the repo `p2` exists in my `Bitbucket` account. If I wanted to `push` some changes in let's say `share-repo`, it would work, but git would also try to push the same changes to the repository `p2`. That's quite a mess I got myself into and I don't know how to solve it.

To sum up, I had this morning a repository called `p2` which I deleted from `bitbucket`, then I deleted it's folder from my computer. Since then, whichever git project I `cd` into, `git remote -v` shows me it has stored - somewhere - information related to the late repo `p2`, on top of the current repo I am working on. Git updating commands - clone, push, pull - won't work unless I create back this damn repo `p2` on `Bitbucket`. Once I do so, git updating commands will apply the commands to the current repo I'm working on, as well as to the repo p2.

`p2` is not the only repository I deleted today, so I am quite curious to know what happened here.

I will gladly take all the help I can get.

Comment: check `~/.gitconfig` for a `[remote "origin"]` section.

Comment: No way... I had looked for a `~/.git` file using tab completion and did not find any. Now looking carefuly (`ls -a ~/`) there is indeed the `~/.gitconfig` file with the information on that remote. Thanks a lot. Don't you want to make an answer on that, so that I validate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. I am speechless. I had made a quick check for a `~/.git-whatever` file using bash autocompletion (tab), it did not work so I blindly assumed the issue was somewhere else. Patrick's comment shed the light: I carefully checked using `ls -a ~/`, the `~/.gitconfig` he wrote about really is here, and it holds the information regarding the remote:

```
$ cat ~/.gitconfig
[user]
   name = myaccount
   email = me@domain.com
[remote "origin"]
   push = git@bitbucket.org:myaccount/p2.git
```

And now I remember the cause for this: while experimenting I used the command `git config --global remote.origin it@bitbucket.org:myaccount/p2.git` and I changed other global configurations. I just did not understand what the `--global` did as I found no alteration in the `repo/.git/config` file.

---

Additional doc on git configuration: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Comment: I don't understand how you have fixed your problem.